# plot two signals with different axis and limits in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

let's consider i am plotting two signals together on the same graph which has different limits and thus i want different axis

```
plot(a)
axis ([-2 10 -2 8])
hold 'on'
plot(b)
axis ([-1 4 -4 7])
hold 'off'
```

where 'a' and 'b' are two signal expression. the problem here is the signals are getting plot but only the second axis is working and plot a is not getting limited to the first specified axis. the reason being the second axis is obviously overwriting the first axes but any idea how to plot both signals with both axis limits?

Comment: So basically you need 2 y axis and 2 x axis on the same axes?

Comment: Ok so in your call to `plot` you need to select the data displayed in those limits right? Like saying "For a plot only those x values that are between -2 and 10 and the y values that are between -2 and 8" ? Sorry if I'm a bit slow to understand haha

Comment: Ok. And what's the size of `a`/how is it organized ? Do you have x values and y values for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the data you wish to plot using logical operators.

Let's consider the case for plot `a`.

Assign each column of `bs` to a variable:

```
x1 = bs(:,1)
y1 = bs(:,2)
```

Then select only the values that meet the condition specified:

```
xPlot = x1(x1 > -2 & x1 < 10)
yPlot = y1(y1 > -2 & y1 < 8)
```

Assuming they both contain the same number of elements you can then plot them.

If not, you need to pad the smaller array with `Nan`, for example, to avoid getting an error about mismatching dimension.

Once you know which array is smaller, you can do it as follows. Let's say in this case `xPlot` is smaller than `yPlot`:

```
m = max(numel(xPlot),numel(yPlot)) %// Just getting the larger dimension
xPlot(numel(xPlot)+1:m) = NaN
```

Now you can call

```
plot(xPlot,yPlot,'b-','LineWidth',2)
```

and that should work. The same applies for the `b` plot.

Hope that helps!

Comment: this looks pretty neat. let me update you tomorrow whether it works or not.

Comment: ok so the problem is it throws the error when i set the limit as                                       xPlot = x1(x1 > -2 & x1 < 5)
yPlot = y1(y1 >1-2 & y1 < 3)                                                                                        the error is that vectors must be of same length.

Comment: ok so try the trick I mentioned in my answer and fill the shorter one with NaN

Comment: ok so i don't know but this plot is not what i expected but since your answer is the best and also it is able to limit the points. i will accept it..cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [plotyy](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) to get 2 different y-axis.

If there is nothing in common in your plots, maybe you should plot them on 2 different axes, like

```
figure('Name', 'Example');
subplot(121);plot(rand(3));
subplot(122);plot(rand(3));
```

**UPDATE**

If you absolutely need two axes, you may try something like this

```
figure('Name', 'plotyy');
h = plotyy([0 1 2 4], 0:4, [4 5], [2 1]);
linkaxes(h, 'off');
axis(h(1), [0 4 0 4]);
axis(h(2), [4 5 1 2]);
```

Comment: no i don't want two plots. that's the problem. i want to plot them on the same graph (so that's the reason i am using hold on). i saw plotyy but i don't think there is plotxx right?

Comment: well, actually ployy returns the handle of the two axes so you you can probably do somehting with that. I'll update my answer with that point.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is something along the lines of `plotyy` but in the other direction, look at  [plotxx](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/317-plotxx-m) function from matlabcentral that does a similar thing in the x-direction.

You may have to tweak it to get it do everything you need, but it will give you a good starting point.

Comment: if i use plotyy then would that not make another axis ? in my case i just want a single y and x axis

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plotyy` which will create 2 y axes with different scales and limits.

Comment: ah but i don't want two y axis. only single x and y axis

Comment: then you can scale / trim the signal itself before plotting it and plot both on the same axes